# Screen orientation in editor in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, rotation, orientation, landscape

In android studio, when run, my program is displayed in landscape mode and works perfectly well. However, when viewing the xml design, the virtual device is displayed in portrait mode. How do I display the xml in landscape mode?

Answer (score 5):

**Short Cut**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> Switch layout orientation **portrait/landscape** backwards [AVD]

> The screenOrientation is the attribute of activity element. The
>   orientation of android activity can be portrait, landscape, sensor,
>   unspecified etc. You need to define it in the AndroidManifest.xml
>   file.

You can add

```
  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

> Your screen will always display in Landscape mode, when you rotate
>   your device, no changes will apply for the current activity.

**Like**

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

Please check official Guideline:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: If you want the layout preview to show the landscape layout, use:
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Answer (score 3):

Click that button next to "Nexus 5".

[image]